# Change insert cursor caret in VS19

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

I am not a fan of the beam/virtual caret for text insertion. I much prefer a horizontal/underline cursor caret.

I tried *guicursor* but it appears to not be supported. How can I configure VsVim or Visual Studio to get the desired cursor caret style?

Example:

[image: example]

Answer (score -1):

You can see how a caret is implemented in VsVim: [VsVim/Src/VimWpf/Implementation/BlockCaret/](https://github.com/VsVim/VsVim/tree/master/Src/VimWpf/Implementation/BlockCaret).